# Zoom meeting software: how to end the call though pressing a physical button?

Tags: meetings, zoom-meeting

I am using Zoom for having to meeting. There is one scenario really bothers me.

1. have a meeting
2. say goodbye
3. smile
4. end the meeting.

it takes several seconds to back to zoom software, click the ending meeting button, and end the meeting.

People have to keep smiling till meeting is ended.

Is it possible to end meeting through pressing a physical button in the meeting device? (e.g. Logical BCC950 monitor)

I am using MacOS.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205683899-Hot-Keys-and-Keyboard-Shortcuts-for-Zoom?mobile_site=true

I did a brief bit of searching and quickly found the Zoom official keyboard shortcut list.

On MacOS use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to end Video. You can then stop smiling and use your hands to end the meeting.

Depending on how your meeting device works, you may be able to modify the keyboard shortcut for ending video to the key pressed on that device. But, as I note: this depends on how your meeting device works and whether it communicates using a compatible method with your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I found zoom provide a shortcut to end the meeting.

```
Command + W
```

[image]